# ufw deny all incoming and outgoing not working!

Tags: ubuntu, security, iptables, ufw

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong. I'm expecting my current rules of "denying all incoming/outgoing" to cripple anything network related, but it's not.

First, I did:

```
sudo ufw default deny incoming

sudo ufw default deny outgoing
```

And then I checked it:

```
sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), deny (outgoing)
New profiles: skip
```

Looks good, and then I reloaded it:

```
sudo ufw enable

sudo ufw reload

sudo service ufw restart
```

Yet, I'm able to post this on the interweb and do everything else.

Comment: What does `ufw show raw` say?  According to the manpage, `status` doesn't show "hardcoded" rules from `/etc/ufw` so you may have some defaults configured there.